# Passing strings as arguments in dplyr verbs

Tags: r, string, dplyr, parameter-passing, data-manipulation

I would like to be able to define arguments for `dplyr` verbs

```
condition <- "dist > 50"
```

and then use these strings  in `dplyr` functions :

```
require(ggplot2)
ds <- cars
ds1 <- ds %>%
   filter (eval(condition))
ds1
```

But it throws in error

```
Error: filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector.
```

The code should evaluate as:

```
  ds1<- ds %>%
     filter(dist > 50)
  ds1
```

Resulting in :

> ds1

```
   speed dist
1     14   60
2     14   80
3     15   54
4     18   56
5     18   76
6     18   84
7     19   68
8     20   52
9     20   56
10    20   64
11    22   66
12    23   54
13    24   70
14    24   92
15    24   93
16    24  120
17    25   85
```

## Question:

How to pass a string as an argument in a `dplyr` verb?

Comment: As I understand it, this is a [work in progress](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/352)

Comment: And now it's completed and part of the standard `dplyr` installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since these 2014 answers, two new ways are possible using [rlang's quasiquotation](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html).

**Conventional hard-coded filter statement.**  For the sake of comparison, the statement `dist > 50` is included directly in `dplyr::filter()`.

```
library(magrittr)

# The filter statement is hard-coded inside the function.
cars_subset_0 <- function( ) {
  cars %>%
    dplyr::filter(dist > 50)
}
cars_subset_0()
```

results:

```
   speed dist
1     14   60
2     14   80
3     15   54
4     18   56
...
17    25   85
```

**rlang approach with NSE (nonstandard evaluation).**  As described in the [Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) vignette, the statement `dist > 50` is processed by [`rlang::enquo()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quotation.html), which "uses some dark magic to look at the argument, see what the user typed, and return that value as a quosure".  Then rlang's [`!!`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html) unquotes the input "so that it’s evaluated immediately in the surrounding context".

```
# The filter statement is evaluated with NSE.
cars_subset_1 <- function( filter_statement ) {
  filter_statement_en <- rlang::enquo(filter_statement)
  message("filter statement: `", filter_statement_en, "`.")

  cars %>%
    dplyr::filter(!!filter_statement_en)
}
cars_subset_1(dist > 50)
```

results:

```
filter statement: `~dist > 50`.
<quosure>
expr: ^dist > 50
env:  global
   speed dist
1     14   60
2     14   80
3     15   54
4     18   56
17    25   85
```

**rlang approach passing a string.**  The statement `"dist > 50"` is passed to the function as an explicit string, and parsed as an expression by [`rlang::parse_expr()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/parse_expr.html), then unquoted by `!!`.

```
# The filter statement is passed a string.
cars_subset_2 <- function( filter_statement ) {
  filter_statement_expr <- rlang::parse_expr(filter_statement)
  message("filter statement: `", filter_statement_expr, "`.")

  cars %>%
    dplyr::filter(!!filter_statement_expr)
}
cars_subset_2("dist > 50")
```

results:

```
filter statement: `>dist50`.
   speed dist
1     14   60
2     14   80
3     15   54
4     18   56
...
17    25   85
```

Things are simpler with  `dplyr::select()`.  Explicit strings need only `!!`.

```
# The select statement is passed a string.
cars_subset_2b <- function( select_statement ) {
  cars %>%
    dplyr::select(!!select_statement)
}
cars_subset_2b("dist")
```

Answer (score 15):

In the next version of dplyr, it will probably work like this:

```
condition <- quote(dist > 50)

mtcars %>%
   filter_(condition)
```

Comment: can't wait. dplyr keeps surprising me with its intuitiveness and intelligence. Thanks, Hadley!

Comment: And what if one wants to pass multiple arguments? Passing a list like `list("dist > 50", "speed > 10")` returns `Error: Can't convert a list to a quosure`

Comment: EDIT: found it: `paste(list('dist > 50', 'speed > 10'), collapse=" & ")`

Answer (score 3):

While they're working on that, here is a workaround using `if`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

ds <- data.frame(attend = c(1:5,NA,7:9,NA,NA,12))

filter_na <- FALSE

filtertest <- function(x,filterTF = filter_na){
  if(filterTF) x else !(x)
}

ds %>%
  filter(attend %>% is.na %>% filtertest)

  attend
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      7
7      8
8      9
9     12

filter_na <- TRUE
ds %>%
  filter(attend %>% is.na %>% filtertest)

  attend
1     NA
2     NA
3     NA
```

Comment: thanks, @AndrewMacDonald! sorry, for not offering a reproducible example earlier

Comment: great, thanks @AndrewMacDonald, this works and on top gives me a simple example of using function with dplyr - something i wanted to have for reference. Thanks again!

Comment: glad it was useful! I edited it above very slightly (one shouldn't use `$` within `filter`!

Comment: I didn't know about $ and didn't notice malfunction (or didn't realize it was due to that?). Thanks for the heads up, i'll keep this mind.